# Best way to detect mouse click after pressing a button in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

My aim is to create a line tool on a program so that when a button is pressed, the user is able to select two points using the left mouse button and after the second click, a straight line should be drawn between the selected points.

Or something similar to the line tool on Microsoft paint if that's easier. So long as the user can draw a line.

The code I have so far is minimal. The problem I have is detecting a mouse click while inside the function below. I originally used a while loop with

```
if (MouseButton.Left == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
```

to check for the clicks however I just created an endless loop as the condition was never satisfied.

My only other idea is to use an event within the LineTool_Click function such as                             `drawingCanvas.MouseDown` but I have no idea how that would work either :/
I'm new to c# /wpf.

```
// When the LineTool button is clicked.....
private void LineTool_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   Point startPoint = new Point(0,0);
   Point endPoint = new Point(0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option is probably to store the start/end points *outside* of the method, and then check within the method if they've been captured or not:

```
// Store these outside of the method
Point lastPoint = new Point(0,0);
bool captured = false;

// When the LineTool button is clicked.....
private void LineTool_Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   if (!this.captured)
   {
       this.captured = true;
       this.lastPoint = e.GetPosition(this.LineTool);
       return;
   }

   // Okay - this is the second click - draw our line:
   this.captured = false; // Make next click "start" again
   Point endPoint = e.GetPosition(this.LineTool);

   // draw from this.lastPoint to endPoint
}
```

Comment: I could be being really dumb here but I got this error: No overload for 'LineTool_Click' matches delegate 'System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler'

Comment: @user2874417 You mentioned you were doing a MouseDown handler, not a click handler.  You'll need to adapt if you want to use click ;)

Comment: To clarify, I have a button in the corner which when pressed I would like it to enter a 'drawing mode' where the user just clicks twice and a line appears between the clicks. The button is named LineTool and LineTool_Click is set to run when the button is first clicked.